# String parsing mechansim to get values

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, expression

I am having the following problem and was hoping someone could tell me if I am using the worst possible mechanism to achieve what ever I am trying to do:

Here is my String that I need to parse:

```
(s(j1) | f(j2) | d(f3) | t(f4) | e(f5) = 5) & v(g) = "0"
```

I need to be able to get j1, j2, f3, f4, f5 and g and basically anything else within parenthesis as separate elements

Here's what I am doing and its not working the way I want it to...

```
String parsedString="";
String delimiter = "[()s(f(d(t(n(v(&|]+");
String[] tokens = parseString.split(delimiterString);
List<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
for (int i=0;i<listOfValues.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Value of "+i+"is "+listOfValues.get(i));
    if(listOfValues.get(i).equals("\r") || listOfValues.get(i).equals("")|| listOfValues.get(i).equals(" "))
    {
         listOfValues.remove(i);
     }
}
```

I am also trying to remove whitespaces and carriage returns, but if there's a better way to do this (obviously my way isn't working) then please let me know.

Comment: FYI, this is a very good site for playing with regexes http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html   Try `\(([^(]+?)\)` as the regex and your string as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
String input = "(s(j1) | f(j2) | d(f3) | t(f4) | e(f5) = 5) & v(g) = \"0\"";
String regex = "\\(([^(]+?)\\)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]\\(([a-z0-9]+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Which when used with your input returns this:

```
j1
j2
f3
f4
f5
g
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex is an easy way to do it as long as there is no serious recursion involved.

```
String s =  "(s(j1) | f(j2) | d(f3) | t(f4) | e(f5) = 5) & v(g) = \"0\"";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\A.*?\\(([^\\(\\)][^\\(\\)]?)\\)(.*)\\z", Pattern.DOTALL);
List<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.matches())
{
    String toAdd = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("adding = " + toAdd);
    listOfValues.add(toAdd);
    s = m.group(2);
    m = p.matcher(s);
}
```

Comment: This includes the parentheses like `[(j1), (j2), (f3), (f4), (f5), (g)]`, OP seems to want `[j1, j2, f3, f4, f5, g]`

Comment: Yes, works now. You're regex seems a bit verbose, though. Look at the regex my answer. Don't need 2 groups and only a single matcher. You need a new matcher for every hit ;)

Comment: No, you have my +1 for posting a working solution. I just find mine more efficient and the regex easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^ ()]+(?=\\))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("(s(j1) | f(j2) | d(f3) | t(f4) | e(f5) = 5) & v(g) = \"0\"");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```